# installing libmysqlclient21 gives error

Tags: apt, mysql

I am trying to install `libmysqlclient21` on databricks as shown below

```
%sh
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get update -y --fix-missing
sudo apt-get install -y libmysqlclient21
```

But I get the below error:

[image]

Comment: Could you insert the error as text instead of an image? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As per your screenshot, it looks like an apt mirror does not have the required .deb file for downloading.

1. You could try selecting an alternate mirror, as per the [below guide](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-select-the-fastest-apt-mirror-on-ubuntu-linux):

- Open the Software & Updates application, then click on the “Download From” drop down box.
- Manually scroll through the list and select your desired mirror, or alternatively just click the “Select best server” button to let Ubuntu do the work for you.

2. Using mirror protocol as part of your `/etc/apt/sources.list` entry, will instruct apt command to fetch mirrors located within your country only.

- In order to use mirror protocol, update all lines within `/etc/apt/sources.list` file from the usual e.g.:
  `deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted`
  to:
  `deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt focal main restricted`
- Repeat the above for all relevant lines where appropriate.
- Run `sudo apt-get update` again.